# How to get data from table using java

Tags: java

i'm trying to execute a simple oracle sql command from java like.
So i have a Utility class in my project where i put these two codes:
1- connection to DB

```
public static Connection DBConnec(){

        Connection cn = null;       
        try{
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

            String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + Util.getPropertyValue("dbHost") + ":" + "1500" + ":" + "ddv";
            //creating connection to Oracle database using JDBC
            cn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, Util.getPropertyValue("User"), Util.getPropertyValue("Password")); 
            System.out.println("Connection...OK");          
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();    
        } catch (SQLException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();        
        }   
        return cn;          
    }
```

2- simple query

```
public static  ResultSet getData(Connection cn){


        ResultSet result2 = null;

        try {                   
                      String sql = ("SELECT * FROM TABLE");     
                         PreparedStatement preStatement = cn.prepareStatement(sql);
                         result2 = preStatement.executeQuery();  

                     } catch (SQLException e) {  
                       e.printStackTrace();         
                         }

                          return result2;   
                              }
```

So i call the first method like this:
public Query(Connection cn ){

```
//Connection to Database
  System.out.println("Connection to Database OK");
  Utility.dbConnec();
```

It 's working perfectly.

Now how can i call the second method:
getData(Connection cn)// it's not working

Please any help.
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need pass dbConnect return value like parameter in the getData method something like:

```
System.out.println("Connection to Database OK");
ResultSet data = Utility.getData(Utility.dbConnec());
```

Comment: no its not working but thank you i have to find another solution